# What's a word to describe someone who thinks quick?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word to describe someone's personality trait that think quick. For example he gets lost in the woods then comes up with a solution on the fly to find his way back home.

Comment: Try "quick-witted."

Comment: not acute/astute just the speed of thinking?

Comment: a quick thinker?

Comment: fast on his feet?

Comment: Witty maybe. Or crafty.

Comment: No word because “thinks quick” is not grammatical. You don’t have to think quickly to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Choose one:

- **sharp-witted**
- **quick-thinking**
- acute
- alert
- astute
- bright
- clever
- intelligent
- keen
- nimble
- on the ball
- perceptive
- quick
- **quick-witted**
- savvy
- sharp
- shrewd
- smart

Comment: I would add *agile*.  (Hopefully the context would make it clear that we're not talking about physical agility.)

Comment: I would call the person in the example **resourceful**.

Answer (score 0):

What's described in the OP implicates on the ability of someone to solve problems rather than simply thinking. In this regard, my suggestion is:

**[Problem solver](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/problem+solver):**

- a thinker who focuses on the problem as stated and tries to synthesize information and knowledge to achieve a solution

**E.g.**

> Having a fascination with the human body and how it works, combined with **his problem-solving personality** and attention to detail, gives him the perfect skill set